# On C# I am getting the CS1061 Error stating ,Object does not have a definition for "Items" and no Extension Method for "Items"

Tags: c#

Here is my coding.  I have researched this through out the website.  Many people seem to have the same issue, but not related to mine.  I am writing a program to access pictures from my laptop, but this error is not letting me access the Picture Directory.  Any help is highly appreciated!!!

```
currentDir = fb.SelectedPath; // Get the selected folder by the user;
textBoxD.Text = currentDir;
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
var files = dirInfo.GetFiles().Where(c=>c.Extension.Equals(".jpg") || c.Extension.Equals(".jpeg") || c.Extension.Equals(".bmp") || c.Extension.Equals(".png"));
foreach (var image in files)
{
    object listBoxImages = null;
    //Add Images/Files to the list box
    listBoxImages.Items.Add(image.Name);
}
```

Comment: Show your assignment to listBoxImages (I assume you are eventually assigning something to it)

Comment: where is this code situated? in a Windows Form? Do you want to display the file names in a `ListBox` ?

Comment: Yes the code is in winform, Visual Studio.  I do want to display file names in a ListBox. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You have two problems. The first, which is the immediate cause of the compilation error is  that `listBoxImages` is defined as an `object`. So all it has is methods and properties of `object` - which does not have `Items` property.

Secondly, You are assigning `null` to `listBoxImages` so even if it had the `Items` property you'd get a `NullReferenceException`

I'm assuming you want to initialize it as a `ListBox` instead. When you do so also make sure to define and initialize it outside of the `foreach` loop because otherwise it will only contain the last item

---

In addition you can refactor your linq a bit to use a `HashSet` of the valid extensions:

```
var validExtensions = new HashSet<string>(new[] { ".jpg", "jpeg", ".bmp", ".png" });
var files = dirInfo.GetFiles().Where(c => validExtensions.Contains(c.Extension));
```

*HashSet `Contains` is performed in `O(1)` so changing from the multiple `||` statements to using this collection doesn't harm performance and is much more extensible and readable*

Comment: @Jason Rhoades - Did this help you understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

listBoxImages is of type `object` . Typecast it to the type of collection and use the items property

Answer (score -1):

Problem is you are trying to add items to listboxImage that has not been initialized.

```
currentDir = fb.SelectedPath; // Get the selected folder by the user;
textBoxD.Text = currentDir;
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
var files = dirInfo.GetFiles().Where(c=>c.Extension.Equals(".jpg") || c.Extension.Equals(".jpeg") || c.Extension.Equals(".bmp") || c.Extension.Equals(".png"));

var listBoxImages = new ListBox(); //I think listBoxImages is of type ListBox control
foreach (var image in files)
{   
    //Add Images/Files to the list box
    listBoxImages.Items.Add(image.Name);
}
```

Comment: Technically, that will be his next problem. The current problem is that he's marked listBoxImages as an `object`

Comment: that is why he is getting issue in his code. if listBoxImages is made type of LIstBox then he can add image name items to that listBoxImages. Moreover taking listBoxImages from loop to outside will prevent multiple init of the control.